# Are any other macOS users having problems building bitmonerod with release-static?

Tags: monerod, macos

I've been running a couple of nodes on macOS for some time now, and I usually pull down new source from the master repo once a week or so and rebuild so I have the latest and greatest. I'm now seeing a link error when building release-static on a fresh install of 10.11.6 (ElCap):

> [ 95%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/bitmonerod
>   Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "___real___cxa_throw", referenced from:
>         ___wrap___cxa_throw in libcommon.a(stack_trace.cpp.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Are any other macOS folks seeing this? Or am I just missing some libraries. I'm using brew, and have these installed:

> brew install boost cmake libevent miniupnpc pkgconfig

The release version is building fine, it's just release-static that is giving this error. I like release-static as then I can just copy the binary over to the other machine and run without having the build environment setup there.

UPDATE
This issue was fixed and release-static began working again soon after I posted the issue to GitHub.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the source code is a rapidly moving target. Questions about building a specific commit are (arguably) on-topic, but more general questions like this one are better suited to GitHub issues.

Comment: Cool. I signed up for GitHub and posted an issue there: https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero/issues/932

Comment: @fluffyponyza I will also vote to close this question based on your comment and the agreement of its poster. Is the issue of when questions relating to errors when building from source are on topic or not worthy of a meta discussion?